# Unable to run ipython-notebook 2.7 with jupyterhub

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to run ipython 2.7 notebooks with jupyterhub on Ubuntu 14.04 - but I haven't been able to figure out a way. Any suggestions?

I know one needs to add kernels in the file ~/.ipython/kernels.json
I have the following in this file:

```
{
 "argv": ["python3", "-m", "IPython.kernel",
          "-f", "{connection_file}"],
 "display_name": "Python 3",
 "language": "python"
}
{
 "argv": ["python2.7", "-m", "IPython.kernel",
      "-f", "{connection_file}"],
 "display_name": "Python 2",
 "language": "python"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`~/.ipython/kernels.json` is not the right path. And theses files are not ment to be edited by hand. Also the file you have is not valid json, the server will be unable to read it if it was in the right place.

use `python2.7 -m IPython kernelspec install-self` and `python3 -m IPython kernelspec install-self` for IPython to put the right files in the right locations.

That being said, even with the kernels files wrong you shoudl be able to start jupyterhub. Do you have other error messages ?

Comment: I am able to start jupyterhub and make ipython3 notebooks.

When I run, `python2.7 -m IPython kernelspec install-self' I get an error message - "python2.7 File not found kernelspec"
Trying to resolve this now.

Comment: I couldnot make the kernelspec work automatically - just created a kernel.json file in jupyter/kernels/python2/

    {
     "display_name": "Python 2",
     "language": "python",
     "argv": [
      "/usr/bin/python2",
      "-c",
      "from IPython.kernel.zmq.kernelapp import main; main()",
      "-f",
      "{connection_file}"
     ]
    }

Comment: The error message is because IPython 3.x is not installed on python2.7. Don't create theses files by hand, you will break things later.