# How to configure JupyterHub to show same notebook types as Jupyter?

Tags: python, configuration, jupyter, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

On Ubuntu 14 I installed Jupyter via pip3 and apt-get. It works. Yet I have a problem: JupyterHub shows one menu for a user:

[image]

while Jupyter notebook shows another:

[image]

Same virtual environments and default configuration.

I use the following comands to start them:

```
sudo jupyter notebook --port=80 --ip=0.0.0.0  --no-browser
sudo jupyterhub --port 80
```

I wonder what shall be changed in JupyterHub to show exactly the same picture as I see in Jupyter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JupyterHub doesn't change how kernelspecs are found or listed, so the most likely cause is that some of your kernels are installed for just one user, and not available to other users on the system. You can see where kernelspecs are with:

```
$ jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels
  python3    /home/you/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
  python2    /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python2
```

Any kernelspecs that are installed in a per-user location (e.g. in your home directory) will not be available to other users. Any kernelspecs that you want to be available to all users on the Hub need to be in a system-wide location (`/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/`).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have Jupyter configured for python2 kernels? See this answer for more details [Unable to run ipython-notebook 2.7 with jupyterhub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30961677/unable-to-run-ipython-notebook-2-7-with-jupyterhub).

Comment: Yes, and I can run python2 in Jupiter notebook